# Why does the last container flicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a set of div's that will animate on hover. I'm using jQuery and the HoverIntent plugin to animate it.

**The HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="grow" style="background-color:#03045E;"></div>
      <div class="grow" style="background-color:#0077B6;"></div>
      <div class="grow" style="background-color:#00B4D8;"></div>
      <div class="grow" style="background-color:#90E0EF;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

... and the **JS Code**

```
$(function() {
    $('.grow').hoverIntent({ 
    over : function() {
        $('.grow').animate({
        'width':'15%'
      },{duration:400,queue:false});
      $(this).animate({
        'width':'55%'
      },{duration:400,queue:false});
    },
    out : function() {
        //we need to check if the mouse is outside the main object to fire a back to original state. Hence, the mouse out effect on the containers itself should do nothing.
    }
  });
  $('.wrapper').hoverIntent({
    out : function() {
        $('.grow').animate({
        'width':'25%'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

It is available here - https://jsfiddle.net/be0u3hfx/12/

I cant seem to understand why the last div flickers on hover of any div! Help!?

Comment: It's because during the size changes, the widths of the elements will occasionally amount to more than 100% total, and when that happens, the browser briefly wraps the last element, making it appear below the first. To prevent that, add `display: flex;` to your wrapper's CSS rules.

Comment: @ChrisG that's a good answer, you should add it

Answer (score 1):

It's because during the size changes, the widths of the elements will occasionally amount to more than 100% total, and when that happens, the browser briefly wraps the last element, making it appear below the first. To prevent that, add `display: flex;` to your wrapper's CSS rules.

Fixed code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.grow').hoverIntent({
    sensitivity: 1, // sensitivity threshold
    interval: 10, // milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
    timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut 
    over: function() {
      $('.grow').animate({
        'width': '15%'
      }, {
        duration: 400,
        queue: false
      });
      $(this).animate({
        'width': '55%'
      }, {
        duration: 400,
        queue: false
      });
    },
    out: function() {}
  });
  $('.wrapper').hoverIntent({
    over: () => {},
    out: function() {
      $('.grow').animate({
        'width': '25%'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.grow {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  /* Original height */
  width: 25%;
  /* Original width */
  float: left;
  /* Just for presentation (Not required) */
  position: relative;
  /* Just for presentation (Not required) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.hoverintent/1.10.1/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grow" style="background-color:#03045E;"></div>
  <div class="grow" style="background-color:#0077B6;"></div>
  <div class="grow" style="background-color:#00B4D8;"></div>
  <div class="grow" style="background-color:#90E0EF;"></div>
</div>
```